# Identification of GM Connector

Tags: chevrolet, connector

I'm trying to identify some connectors for a Chevy Equinox, located on the rear mud flap. I believe these are common GM connectors but I do not know the nomenclature.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: http://www.araymondtinnerman.com/industrial/products/families

Comment: Those pictures are tiny @ffejrekaburb, it's hard to tell anything from them.

Answer (score 6):

The second image shows a U-nut,speed nut or clip nut depending on the manufacturer. They are available at most auto parts suppliers. They are available in a variety of thread sizes and the length of the clip also varies with application. The easiest means of selecting the correct size is to remove one and match it at the store.

Comment: No disagreement it's a clip nut, one thing I would say is that with specialty clips like that it's often the same price to buy a whole set online than to buy a few specific ones from a store. I usually do that now, I may not use even a quarter of the total but it means I probably have what I need for future repairs.